# Join two sql queries side by side with no column common

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to join the results of two queries horizontally. 
Consider a query below which will return two rows:

```
Select * 
  from Salary 
 where sal > 10000
```

The result of the query above should be joined side by side with the result of the query below which will again return two rows.Or I need to just concatenate the two result sets:

```
Select 'xyz' from dual
union
Select 'abc' from dual
```

Please suggest how this can be done as I tried to do this with the query below but it returns a cartesian product:

```
Select * 
  from (Select * 
          from salary 
         where sal > 10000) TEMP1,
       (Select 'xyz' from dual
        union
        Select 'abc' from dual) TEMP2
```

Comment: Could you be clearer about what you'd like your result set to look like, if you do not want a cross join?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by joining on rownum like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT view_name, rownum AS r FROM all_views WHERE rownum <=10)
    FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT table_name, rownum AS r FROM all_tables WHERE rownum <=10) USING (r)
```

In your case this would look like (untested):

```
Select * from
    (Select salary.*, rownum AS r from salary where sal>10000) TEMP1
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT temp2.*, rownum r FROM
        (Select 'xyz' from dual
        union
        Select 'abc' from dual) TEMP2)
    USING (r)
```

Comment: Within your first query can you refer to column from query 1 in query 2? I know it will throw an error but is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can introduce an artificial join column:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT s.*, ROWNUM ID FROM Salary s WHERE sal > 10000) q1
  JOIN (SELECT 'xyz' col1, 1 ID
          FROM dual
        UNION
        SELECT 'abc' col1, 2 ID FROM dual) q2 ON q1.id = q2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help.

But what I need is a bit complicated. I have updated the previous query to be somewhat like below instead of simple query that I posted before `(SELECT * FROM Salary WHERE sal > 10000)`:

```
SELECT name, sal, address 
FROM (SELECT e1.name, s1.sal, s1.grade, s2.address FROM Emp e1, salary s1, 
    (Select empcode, address FROM Address WHERE empcode LIKE 'NY%') s2
    WHERE e1.hiredate =201001
    AND s1.sal>10000)
```

I know the above query does not make much of a relevance. However, this is similar to what I need actually. I am not posting the original one as that is very complicated but if this can be done for this query, then I will be able to replicate the same on the original one as well.

Thank you,

Sharon

Comment: What did you end up doing do you remember?