# MySQL Union: Result Columns Side-by-Side

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have 2 SELECT Statements that are Combined by UNION.  Instead of having all the results stacked in order from one row to the next, I would like to have the 2nd SELECT statement's results/Columns added NEXT TO the 1st SELECT Statement's results/Columns:

Following are the two queries, but simple feedback would probably suffice.

QUERY 1

```
  select    
      LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4) Year_Max,

      RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2) Quarter_Max,

      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=03,'Enero a Marzo',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=06,'Abril a Junio',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=09,'Julio a Septiembre',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=12,'Octubre a Diciembre',
      '')
      ))) Quarter_Name,

      ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Quarterly_yield_Max

from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres A
where     A.ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA
And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
And       LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4) = ( select    MAX(left(F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4)) - 0
                              from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres
                              where     ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA )
```

QUERY 2

```
select    
      LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4) Year_Max_Less_One,

      RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2) Quarter_Max_Less_One,

      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=03,'Enero a Marzo',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=06,'Abril a Junio',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=09,'Julio a Septiembre',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=12,'Octubre a Diciembre',
      '')
      ))) Quarter_Name,

      ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Quarterly_yield_Max_Less_One

from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres A
where     A.ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA
And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
And       LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4) = ( select    MAX(left(F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4)) - 1
                              from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres
                              where     ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA )
```

Comment: While we wait for a full answer, consider looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408273/join-two-sql-queries-side-by-side-with-no-column-common

Comment: Thanks, I saw that one already but could not figure out how to apply it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can put result in temporary table, add serial column, after that left/right join  tables by id column.

There are no pure sql way for this. In mysql you also can do something liek this:

```
select tab1.a,tab1.b,tab1.c,tab2.a,tab2.b,tab2.c from 
 (SELECT @rowno:=@rowno+1 as id,a,b,c from tab1 where something) as tab1 left join
 (SELECT @rowno:=@rowno+1 as id,a,b,c from tab2 where something) as tab2 on tab2.id=tab1.id
```

But only if you know that tab1 have more rows. Sure you can calc first, but it will be complex query.

I am unsure about join in your queries, maybe based on year? You know better.

Comment: Unfortunately my SQL skill level is novice to intermediate and I am not familiar with your syntax :(  ... @rowno ... as id,a,b,c

Comment: that is just create id column with 1,2,3, etc. probalby you not needed since you want join it on year+quarter,right?